# Why is the residue ring of the coordinate ring equal to the field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $A$ is a commutative ring with unit, then for each $x \in$ Spec $A$, the residue field at $x$ is defined (in Shafarevich) to be the field of fractions of the quotient of $A$ by the corresponding prime ideal. It is denoted by $k(x)$. Then he says, "If $A=k[X]$ is the coordinate ring of an affine variety $X$ defined over an algebraically closed field $k$ then $k(x)=k$." Could someone explain exactly why this is true? It seems to require some theorem in commutative algebra.

Comment: It is a finite extension of an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Are you sure you did not mean the quotient by $x$ of the localisation of $A$ at $x$ (i.e. the *residue field* $\dfrac{A_x}{x_x}$ of the local ring $A_x$)? The claim does not seem true with your definition $k(x)=\operatorname{Frac}\dfrac{A}{x}$: pick $X$ an irreducible algebraic variety and the prime ideal $x=0$. Then $k(x)=\operatorname{Frac} k[X]$ is clearly a trascendent extension of $k$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Taking the quotient of the localization instead of the field of fractions of the quotient doesn't make a difference.  The result just isn't true unless $x$ is maximal.

Comment: From what I'm reading, it seems that you have to argue that FFR($A/p) \cong A_p/pA_p$, that $A_p$ is finitely generated over $A$, and that $A_p/pA_p$ is a finite algebraic extension of $k$.

Comment: Could you give a page number, or at least the chapter?  I found only two occurrences of "residue field" in Shafarevich's book, and neither is the one you cite above.

Comment: p.7 of Basic Algebraic Geometry 2, 3rd edition, section 1.1.2. "We can associate with each point x $\in$ SpecA the field of fractions of the quotient ring by the corresponding prime ideal. This field is called the residue field at x and denoted by k(x). Thus we have a homomorphism
A → k(x), whose kernel is the prime ideal we are denoting by x. We write f (x) for the image of f ∈ A under this homomorphism. If A = k[X] is the coordinate ring of an affine variety X defined over an algebraically closed field k then k(x) = k."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true in general; this is only true when $x$ is a *maximal* ideal of $A$.  In that case, the quotient $A/x$ is a field, so $k(x)$ is just $A/x$.  So $k(x)=A/x$ is a field which is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, which implies it is a finite extension of $k$ by [Zariski's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma).  Since $k$ is algebraically closed, we must have $k(x)=k$.

Comment: OK, thank you for the clarification. There must be a mistake in Shafarevich, then. So, to clarify, in the case when $x$ is a maximal ideal in $A$, then the residue field $k(x)$ coincides with $k$, but otherwise it could be some entirely unrelated field.

Comment: Well, it's not entirely unrelated: it's an extension of $k$.  But if $x$ is not maximal, it will be a nontrivial extension.

Comment: @CoffeeBliss I don't have Shafarevich on me, but assuming this is book he wrote by himself (not the more advanced series with several authors) then I recall it being incredibly classical. In particular, I would be shocked if he wasn't always talking about $\text{MaxSpec}$--in other words, I doubt he ever means $x$ to be anything but a closed point.

Comment: @EricWofsey How do you prove that the residue field at any point is an extension of $k$?

Comment: There is a homomorphism $k\to A$ and a homomorphism from $A$ to the residue field, giving a homomorphism from $k$ to the residue field.